# Sharing one module between two pages

Tags: javascript, webpack

I am creating a web app and it consists of two pages: main page and admin page. I have two entry points, and I have a competently reusable authentication module that I've done for admin page. And now I want to use it for main page also. 
I tried duplicating the file, it works, but I feel that it is not right way of doing it.

```
    module.exports = {
  entry: {
    app: './src/Main/App.js',
    adminApp: './src/Admin/Admin.js'}
    ,
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist/assets'),
    filename: '[name].bundle.js'
  }
```

Comment: Actually, that's how I use it. From what I can see, this is the right way. Maybe someone can show you if there's a better way.